# Javascript, close tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

[W3Schools - Fade in tab](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs_fade)

I am using this code. For example when I click London, a new tab content is opening. But it is not closing. I want to close it so I added a close button in main div. But I couldn't write that script. What should I do about closing tabcontent?

Comment: If you show us what you've tried that would be helpful.

Comment: If you want your users to close the tab once they select it, you may wish to consider using an accordion interface instead. Since you're already using Javascript, consider the jQuery accordion UI options: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle with what you are looking for.
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Popatop15/ssz8ohd4/1/)

```
<h3>Fade in Tabs</h3>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,     'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class='tablinks' onclick='hideText()'>Hide</a></li>
```

```
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function hideText() {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't think you realized the functions were already there, but I just moved the code into a seperate function and added a button to hide what was being shown currently, and removed any active classes.

Comment: Code is working. I am grateful to you. Thanks for all